# How to migrate this Make and Autotools project with multiple source subdirectories to CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

I'm currently using recursive make and autotools and am looking to migrate to CMake for a project that looks something like this:

```
lx/ (project root)
    src/
        lx.c (contains main method)
        conf.c
        util/
            str.c
            str.h
            etc.c
            etc.h
        server/
            server.c
            server.h
            request.c
            request.h
        js/
            js.c
            js.h
            interp.c
            interp.h
    bin/
        lx (executable)
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If there's never any source higher than the lx/src directory, then there's no need for the **lx/CMakeLists.txt** file. If there is, it should look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(lx)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)

# And possibly other commands dealing with things
# directly in the "lx" directory
```

...where the subdirectories are added in library dependency order. Libraries that depend on nothing else should be added first, and then libraries that depend on those, and so on.

**lx/src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(lx_exe)

add_subdirectory(util)
add_subdirectory(js)
add_subdirectory(server)

set(lx_source_files conf.c lx.c)
add_executable(lx ${lx_source_files})

target_link_libraries(lx server)
  # also transitively gets the "js" and "util" dependencies
```

**lx/src/util/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(util_source_files
  etc.c
  etc.h
  str.c
  str.h
)
add_library(util ${util_source_files})
```

**lx/src/js/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(js_source_files
  interp.c
  interp.h
  js.c
  js.h
)
add_library(js ${js_source_files})

target_link_libraries(js util)
```

**lx/src/server/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(server_source_files
  request.c
  request.h
  server.c
  server.h
)
add_library(server ${server_source_files})

target_link_libraries(server js)
  # also transitively gets the "util" dependency
```

Then, in a command prompt:

```
mkdir lx/bin
cd lx/bin

cmake ..
  # or "cmake ../src" if the top level
  # CMakeLists.txt is in lx/src

make
```

By default, the lx executable will end up in the "lx/bin/src" directory using this exact layout. You can control what directory it ends up in by using the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY target property and the set_property command.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:set_property

Refer to target_link_libraries libs either by CMake target name, if the lib is built as a CMake target via add_library, or by full path to the library file otherwise.

See also, the output of "cmake --help-command target_link_libraries", or any other cmake command, and the full online documentation for cmake commands found here:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#section_Commands

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:target_link_libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot—but how does the "transitive" getting the "js" and "util" dependencies work?

Comment: That's a feature of CMake - it tracks target_link_libraries commands through the whole tree to build the dependency graph in internal data structures, and uses that to generate correct link command lines.

Comment: Because I'm too lazy to list files, I found FILE(GLOB_RECURSE sourceVar ./ *.cpp *.c *.h) to be very useful.  You can also use GLOB which doesn't recurse into sub-sub folders.  Otherwise thanks DLRdave for getting me started on CMake as well.

Answer (score 1):

Steinberg VST3 library has a reusable method which recursively loops through subdirectories and adds them if they include a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# add every sub directory of the current source dir if it contains a CMakeLists.txt
function(smtg_add_subdirectories)
    file(GLOB subDirectories RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *)
    foreach(dir ${subDirectories})
        if(IS_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${dir}")
            if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${dir}/CMakeLists.txt")
                add_subdirectory(${dir})
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach(dir)
endfunction()
```

https://github.com/steinbergmedia/vst3_cmake/blob/master/modules/SMTG_AddSubDirectories.cmake