# Application crash when using library from the program compiled with make

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I'm making scientific calculator in command line in c++ for my usage and also for practice. I have a problem with compiling it using cmake with mingw on windows. These are my source files:

main.ccp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

#include "ExpressionCalculations/ExpressionParser.h"

int main()
{
   std::string humanReadableExpression;
   std::cout<<"Enter expression\n";
   std::getline(std::cin, humanReadableExpression);
   std::cout<<humanReadableExpression;
   ExpressionCalculations::ExpressionParser parser;
   auto&& expression = parser.GenerateRpnExpression(humanReadableExpression);
   return 0;
}
```

ExpressionParser.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace ExpressionCalculations
{

    class ExpressionParser
    {
        public:
            std::unique_ptr<std::string> GenerateRpnExpression(std::string &humanReadableExpression);
        private:
            // other code
};
```

}

ExpressionParser.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

#include "ExpressionParser.h"

namespace ExpressionCalculations
{
std::unique_ptr<std::string> ExpressionParser::GenerateRpnExpression(
    std::string& humanReadableExpression)
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> rpnExpression;
    *rpnExpression="3456";

    return rpnExpression;
}
```

These are cmake files

main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (ScientificCalculator_exe)
add_subdirectory(ExpressionCalculations)

add_executable(ScientificCalculator main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ScientificCalculator ExpressionCalculations)
```

module CMakeList.txt

```
set(calculators ExpressionParser.h ExpressionParser.cpp)

add_library(ExpressionCalculations ${calculators})
```

When I run it , I can see Enter expression and pass input. Then I get Segmentation fault. However when I remove declaration of ExpressionParser and auto&& expression the  string is shown, a string can be inputted and shown in the command.  I checked configuration question [multiple directories under cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352123/multiple-directories-under-cmake), https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181455/A-CMake-tutorial-for-Visual-Cplusplus-developers but it seems that I correctly made cmake files. I have no idea why it doesn't work. I use the latest mingw64 on windows with default make compilation parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging program compiled with just g++ I found the problem. It was misunderstanding of unique_ptr' default constructor behaviour. I thought it would initialize std::string but after reading doc and checking it it does not initialize object and generates nullptr. Then I looked into Scott Myers's Modern Effective C++ how to initialize the unique_ptr. Instead of `std::unique_ptr<std::string> rpnExpression;` I used `auto rpnExpression = std::make_unique<std::string>();`. It works like charm. I checked compiling through cmake and there were not any problems.

Answer (score 0):

From the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) on unique_ptr:

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable.

In your `ExpressionParser::GenerateRpnExpression` function you are attempting to copy the unique_ptr out of the function when you should be moving it. Try `return std::move(rpnExpression)`