# Issue with CMake linking library

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm having issues with CMake not finding files, but after scouring a few other threads I've still not found any luck. Here is my file structure:

```
Game/ (root)
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    GameLib1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        GameLib1_1/
            CMakeLists.txt
            file1.cpp
            file1.h
            file2.cpp
            file2.h
```

In `Game/CMakeLists.txt` I have the following:

```
project(Game)

add_subdirectory(GameLib1)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GameLibrary)
```

In `Game/GameLib1/CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
add_subdirectory(GameLib1_1)
```

And in `Game/GameLib1/GameLib1_1/CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
set(GameLibrary_src_files StateMan.cpp StateMan.h
                    State.cpp State.h)

add_library(GameLibrary ${GameLibrary_src_files})
```

But when I try to build, I get errors in my main file trying to include files from `file1.h` and `file2.h`, specifically the error being:

```
[build] /home/user/Game/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: State.h: No such file or directory

[build]     2 | #include <file1.h>
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

I'm just not sure what I've done wrong with linking the files to main.cpp. Could someone help me out in showing me where I've made an error?

Comment: Your are missing a target_include_directories() for the GameLibrary target

Comment: @drescherjm Where might I add that in? in  Game/CMakeLists.txt below the  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp) line?

Comment: After `add_library(GameLibrary ${GameLibrary_src_files})`

Comment: You need to add it for the executable target `${PROJECT_NAME}`. So add it after the `add_executable` command.

Comment: side note: target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE/PUBLIC GameLibrary) add visibility to you deps

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeLists.txt appears to be missing a target_include_directories() to add an additional include directory for the targets that use the GameLibrary target.

After `add_library(GameLibrary ${GameLibrary_src_files})` in your CMakeLists.txt for GameLibrary add the following: `target_include_directories(GameLibrary PUBLIC .)` then the targets that use GameLibrary will have the additional include directory. The `.` specifies the current folder. You can also use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` instead of the `.` to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thankyou! This fixed it. I'm new to CMake and roughly followed from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352123/multiple-directories-under-cmake , would the user for this post not run into the same issue as I?

Comment: I think that post could have the same issue depending on how they use `#include`  in the targets.